# Как редактировать строку js?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть строка: '0.123456789'.

Нужно с помощью js удалить лишнее после точки '.', то есть должно получиться так: '0.12'.

Jquery присутствует!

Comment: [toFixed()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed)

Comment: @Deonis, но ведь в вопросе речь о строке, а не числе

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Благодарить @Deonis.

```js
var str = 0.123456789;
str = str.toFixed(2);
console.log(str);
```

Подробнее о `.toFixed()` - [тут](http://learn.javascript.ru/number#num-tofixed-precision) или [тут](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed).

Comment: Ворнинг: речь о строке, значит логичнее `(+str).toFixed(2)`.

Answer (score 3):

```
Str = 12.422242;
Str = Str.split(".");
Str2 = Str[1].substring(0,2);
Out = Srt[0] + Str2
```